# What causes Erlang runtime error {undef,[{rand,uniform,[2],[]},...]}?

Tags: erlang

When executing an implementation of the Tarry distributed algorithm, a problem occurs that I don't know how to address: a crash containing the error `{undef,[{rand,uniform,[2],[]}`. My module is below:

```
-module(assign2_ex).
-compile(export_all).

%% Tarry's Algorithm with depth-first version
start() ->
    Out = get_lines([]),
    Nodes = createNodes(tl(Out)),
    Initial = lists:keyfind(hd(Out), 1, Nodes),
    InitialPid = element(2, Initial),
    InitialPid ! {{"main", self()}, []},
    receive
        {_, List} ->
            Names = lists:map(fun(X) -> element(1, X) end, List),
            String = lists:join(" ", lists:reverse(Names)),
            io:format("~s~n", [String])
    end.

get_lines(Lines) ->
    case io:get_line("") of
        %% End of file, reverse the input for correct order
        eof -> lists:reverse(Lines);
        Line ->
            %% Split each line on spaces and new lines
            Nodes = string:tokens(Line, " \n"),
            %% Check next line and add nodes to the result
            get_lines([Nodes | Lines])
    end.

%% Create Nodes
createNodes(List) ->
    NodeNames = [[lists:nth(1, Node)] || Node <- List],
    Neighbours = [tl(SubList) || SubList <- List],
    Pids = [spawn(assign2_ex, midFunction, [Name]) || Name <-NodeNames],                         
    NodeIDs = lists:zip(NodeNames, Pids),
    NeighbourIDs = [getNeighbours(N, NodeIDs) || N <- lists:zip(NodeIDs,   Neighbours)],
    [Pid ! NeighbourPids || {{_, Pid}, NeighbourPids} <- NeighbourIDs],
    NodeIDs.

getNeighbours({{Name, PID}, NeighboursForOne}, NodeIDs) ->
    FuncMap = fun(Node) -> lists:keyfind([Node], 1, NodeIDs) end,
    {{Name, PID}, lists:map(FuncMap, NeighboursForOne)}.

midFunction(Node) ->
    receive
        Neighbours -> tarry_depth(Node, Neighbours, [])
    end.

%% Tarry's Algorithm with depth-first version
%% Doesn't visit the nodes which have been visited
tarry_depth(Name, Neighbours, OldParent) ->
    receive
        {Sender, Visited} ->
            Parent = case OldParent of [] -> [Sender]; _ -> OldParent end,
            Unvisited = lists:subtract(Neighbours, Visited),
            Next = case Unvisited of
                       [] -> hd(Parent);
                       _ -> lists:nth(rand:uniform(length(Unvisited)), Unvisited)
                   end,
            Self = {Name, self()},
            element(2, Next) ! {Self, [Self | Visited]},
            tarry_depth(Name, Neighbours, Parent)
    end.
```

Comment: What version of Erlang/OTP are you using? You should always include that kind of information in your questions. Note that the [`rand` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) exists only in 18.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

An `undef` error means that the program tried to call an undefined function.  There are three reasons that this can happen for:

- There is no module with that name (in this case `rand`), or it cannot be found and loaded for some reason
- The module doesn't define a function with that name and arity.  In this case, the function in question is `uniform` with one argument.  (Note that in Erlang, functions with the same name but different numbers of arguments are considered separate functions.)
- There is such a function, but it isn't exported.

You can check the first by typing `l(rand).` in an Erlang shell, and the second and third by running `rand:module_info(exports).`.

In this case, I suspect that the problem is that you're using an old version of Erlang/OTP.  As noted in [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html), the `rand` module was introduced in release 18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Will be good if you provide the version of Erlang/OTP you are using for future questions as Erlang has changed a lot over the years. As far as i know there is no `rand:uniform` with arity 2 at least in recent Erlang versions and that is what you are getting the `undef` error, for that case you could use `crypto:rand_uniform/2` like `crypto:rand_uniform(Low, High).` Hope this helps :)